# Firefox compatiblity issue for CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I am having some trouble with firefox v60 with  the below code:

```
.btn:focus, .btn:active {
  background-color: orange !important;
  /*background: red !important;*/
}
.btn-primary{
    border-color: #9b9e9e !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background-color: #9b9e9e !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zsvdph8r/7/

I want to change the color of button once its clicked but the color doesn't persist for that button. Its working fine for chrome and firefox v52.

Can someone help me with it?

Thanks

Comment: ff v69 , works like chrome. orange bg is lost once clicking outside the button. this is the regular behavior from the code you provide.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see is that `:focus` is an issue, when we click on button focus remains there on chrome over the button but not in firefox. That's how these browsers work differently here.

`.btn:active` is the right code here which will add color or any transition on click and disappears after completing the task.

But if you persist on same then change button to `<a>` tag and use

```
.btn:active {
  color: orange;
}
```

This will solve your problem, but you might need to add more styling to make link look like button if you wish to.

Comment: Thanks for your response but even after changing it to <a> it's still the same. :|

Comment: Here is the fiddle to help you more.
https://jsfiddle.net/junaidmasoodi/qekfhbco/8/

It works both in Chrome as well as Firefox.